# Make report after running multiple JMX files

Tags: jmeter, java-me

I am trying to generate a meaningful report for business owners that reflects the system's behavior during the run of multiple groups of test cases separated in different JMX files.

I have created a make command to run all tests one by one, producing result files. However, afterwords, I don't like the idea of creating a report per file, as business owners would probably want to read just one consistent document. What is the normal approach of running multiple JMX files and producing reports?

Comment: I use LaTeX and produce a custom report off of the JMX data.    Nothing stops you from doing the same.  Drop me an private message if you want to see an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [Merge Results](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/) plugin which can consolidate different test executions, it's mainly designed for comparison of different test runs but you can also use it for combining the test results into a single [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles).

Merge Results plugin can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)

Alternatively if you're running tests one by one you can use the same output file via [`-l` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) so first test will create results file and subsequent tests will append new results/metrics to that file.